# Reload Not working on Ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad

Following is my code , where I am reloading the page on click of modal button . it working on PC , But not on Ipad.

```
 $(".yes_continue").off('click').click(function () {

                $("#data_variation_step1").modal("hide");
                sessionStorage.setItem("continue", 'yes');
                window.location.reload(true);
                //alert('AUEEE')


            });
```

Tried these too

- `setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = $(location).attr('href')},500);`
- `window.location.reload();`
- `location.reload();`
- `$(".yes_continue").bind("click touchstart",function () {`
- `$(".yes_continue").on("click touchstart tap touch",function () {`
- `$(document).on("click touchstart tap", ".yes_continue", function () {`

what may be the solution

> **Note :** The modal hides , that means the click works but not the reload
>   code ,and it does not alert too.. But alerts on PC
>
> **UPDATE:** Problem is with `sessionStorage.setItem("continue", 'yes');`
>
> 1. If I use private browsing on Ipad chrome. It does not reload. But if I remoe sessionStorage code then reload works.
> 2. If I use non-private browsing the reload works even if I have sessionStorage code.But it does not set any value in session.   So my
>      question is now somewhat got twisted. I dont know how to store value
>      for Ipad, Tried with localStorage too

Comment: Think this may have been answered here: 
[Jquery click not working with ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892863/jquery-click-not-working-with-ipad)

Comment: @JohnDetlefs : ok I will try one by one and update my question .. 1 st solution did not work

Comment: @JohnDetlefs : tried still not working

Comment: Is the modal over a video?

Comment: @Alessio . No.................

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an issue that can come up with ios browsers

Try adding this css:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

More details here: [jQuery click events not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in Safari on my iPad with latest iOS version and it works just fine.

You can also try to reload it with `window.location = window.location.href`

btw I run a small server on my localhost with [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) so you can try it here http://a42fc986.ngrok.io/ (will be available for a short time)

For test I've used this simple code:

```
<div>
    <span>window.location.reload(true)=></span>
    <button class="yes_continue_1st">Press me (button)</button>
    <span class="yes_continue_1st">Press me (span)</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>window.location = window.location.href=></span>
    <button class="yes_continue_2nd">Press me</button>
    <span class="yes_continue_2nd">Press me (span)</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".yes_continue_1st").off('click').click(function () {
        alert("before location.reload");
        window.location.reload(true);
        alert("after location.reload");
    });

    $(".yes_continue_2nd").off('click').click(function () {
        alert("before location.href");
        window.location = window.location.href;
        alert("after location.href");
    });
</script>
```