# Portable way to get Rx stream of all mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, dom-events

I wrote React component which listens to few types of js events (click, scroll, keyup). For the first time it seems work's well, but I noticed that on my IPad click events are ignored. I attached my Ipad to Safari remote debugger but haven't found any errors in console.

I think the problem is in the following line.

`const windowClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'click');`

it works in Chrome and Desktop Safary but doesn't work on my Ipad.

My question is:
how to get portable Rx stream of all click events on the web page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery click not working with ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892863/jquery-click-not-working-with-ipad)

Comment: This is not related to rxjs - have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892863/jquery-click-not-working-with-ipad

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem few months ago and solved this by changing the event listener. The "click" event is at first for desktop applications with a real mouse or touchpad. It takes 300ms until the event is triggered because the browser waits for an additional click to trigger a "dblclick" event. The webkit browser fire an "touchstart" event immediately after you touch the screen.