# .on("click") does not work on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, click

I noticed that

```
$("body").on("click", "#id", function(event) {...
```

does not work on iOS while

```
$("#id").on("click", function(event) {...
```

works perfectly. Same site, same jQuery (latest), same DOM. I can't use the latter because #id is added dynamically.

Ideas?

Comment: [No problems here](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/YBxyw/). Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code. If you connect your iOS device to a Mac, you can use desktop Safari to view console errors in mobile Safari: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Comment: I did that and always debug using safari on my mac. @PalashMondal solved my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try as follows once:

```
$(document).on("click touchstart", "#id", function(event) {...
```

Comment: Just curious - what is the effect of using `document` instead of `body` ?

Comment: hero of my day :) used "touchend" instead as this feels more naturally... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add click and not use touch events you can do this (although it does involve agent sniffing):

```
// Check if it is iOS
var isiOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);

if(isiOS === true) {

    // Store -webkit-tap-highlight-color as this gets set to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) in the next part of the code
    var tempCSS = $('a').css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color');

    $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer')                                    // Make iOS honour the click event on body
             .css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');     // Stops content flashing when body is clicked

    // Re-apply cached CSS
    $('a').css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', tempCSS);

}
```

See more at http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/post/124-add-a-click-event-to-html-or-body-on-ios-using-jquery/